# Why should I STILL use --with-boost for ./configure when I exported PATH variable for boost directory

Tags: environment-variables, paths, boost

I would love to hear your explanations and methods of solutions for the problem that I have been facing for such a long time by now.

I am working in a remote cluster where sudo command is not allowed and any operation on directories above $HOME branch is not permitted 
(`$HOME=/storage/5/trentalove`)

I need to configure

```
$HOME/external/trentacoollime
```

with boost library, which I installed in `$HOME/boost_1_65_1` using the boost_1_65_1.tar.bz2 source from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_65_1.html

(Please note that `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` is not allowed.)

Then, I define my PATH variable in .bash_profile and export as
`export PATH = $HOME/boost_1_65_1:$PATH'

However, when I configure in $HOME/external/trentacoollime directory, with

```
./configure
```

I was prompted with an error message

> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version>=1.41.0

When I configure with

```
./configure --with-boost=../../boost_1_65_1
```

It gave me no error message and successfully configured.

My guess is that since I defined and exported the PATH variable to the boost directory, I need not have the `--with-boost=../../boost_1_65_1` option when I execute the `./configure` command. However, I needed it.

Could someone explain what I am missing?

p.s. I did the same thing in my own machine with `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, which installed boost_1_65_1 under `/usr/include` directory. 
Then I could still configure the `$HOME/external/trentacoollime` with just `./configure` and no `--with-boost=` option ($PATH being defined in the same way as in the cluster).
However, please note that I can not implement the same strategy in the cluster since I do not have permission for sudo nor any kind of mv, cp, ln command to `/usr/include`, which is at a higher branch than my `$HOME` directory.

Comment: `PATH` determines where the shell looks for executable files - AFAIK it has no effect on where build tools look for header files

Comment: Could you give me any suggestion how to make ./configure command to look for $HOME/boost_1_65_1 directory without giving --with-boost option?

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to do this - if the `./configure` script provides a `--with-boost` option, then that's really the most sensible thing to use. You could try setting an include path via one of the commonly respected environment variables e.g. `export CXXFLAGS='-I $HOME/boost_1_65_1'`

Comment: Thank you for your keep up. I get your point, I can still use --with-boost=../../Boost_1_65_1 option.

Comment: However, the real problem comes into my next command which is `make`. I do not know any option that corresponds to `--with-boost` of `./configure` command. After completing `./configure` command successfully with `--with-boost=../../Boost_1_65_1`, I have to execute make.

Comment: However, since I do not know how to give boost path directory for GNU make command, I simply type `make` in my terminal, and it gives me error message: `Error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp` is not found. However, I can see that `share_ptr.hpp` header file DOES EXIST in my `$HOME/Boost_1_65_1/boost` directory.

Comment: The purpose of `./configure` is usually to **create** a suitable `Makefile` - using the header and library locations passed to it, if they are not in the "standard" places. If `make` is not finding `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` then it suggests you didn't give the correct argument to `--with-boost`. What is the complete path to `shared_ptr.hpp`?

Comment: It is a clear demonstration that my make command is not working because GNU make command does NOT access my `$HOME/Boost_1_65_1` to search for the given header file. Thus, I need the make command to access the `$HOME/Boost_1_65_1` directory when executed. I will try your suggestion of `export CXXFLAGS='-I $HOME/boost_1_65_1'` to see if it works

Comment: the complete path is `$HOME/Boost_1_65_1/boost/shared_ptr.hpp. The `shared_ptr.hpp` is just ONE of many header files that the terminal is showing onto me.

Comment: It's hard to give specifics without knowing *what* you're trying to build - my *guess* is that `--with-boost` expects a top-level directory that contains the "usual" Unix subdirectory tree (`/lib`, `/inlude` etc.). You *may* find that the best way to handle this is to create `$HOME/include` and move the `boost` subdirectory from `Boost_1_65_1` to it - then use `--with-boost=$HOME`

Comment: I moved /boost_1_65_1/boost to /boost_1_65_1, renamed /boost_1_65_1 as /boost, and gave argument --with-boost=$HOME/boost.